# This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.

Tags: java, android

i get this exception when i try to launch my app, why?

```
Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

> STYLES.XML

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Someone can help me?

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error specify that your activity does not support `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR`

so you can use a `toolbar` in your activity layout instead.

Here is [Good Example](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html) for that.

Additionally you need to set your `activity` theme properly in Manifest.

Use:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".activity.YourActivity" //the activity where you got the crash
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">  //add this
```